# Find the sum of the following series. $\sum_{m=1}^{ \infty }\frac{{(-1)^m}{+3}}{5^m}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following series. $\sum_{m=1}^{ \infty  }\frac{{(-1)^m}{+3}}{5^m}$

**My attempt**

$\sum_{m=1}^{ \infty  }$ $\frac{(-1)^m}{5^m}$ + 3$\sum_{m=1}^{ \infty  }$ $\frac{1}{5^m}$

But, I am stuck here... Can anyone show how to do this

Comment: Hint: $\;\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{ \infty  } \left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^m\,$ is the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\left|-\frac15\right|=\frac15<1$,$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{5^m}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(-\frac15\right)^m=\frac{-\frac15}{1+\frac15}=-\frac16.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac15\right)^m$ is also a geometric series and I got $\frac{1}{4}$ and then I added $\frac{-1}{6}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$, is this correct

Comment: @tienlee That's it!